# java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream - Zipping large files faster?

Tags: java, android, zip, buffer, large-files

I am wondering how could I speed up the zipping process of 40+ image files, in my android app.

Clients are sending images, which needs to be compressed or placed into a folder before uploading on the server. Now I use the bellow method, but this way files are zipped in about 20-30 seconds, while the phone appears to be frozen and users tend to exit the app :(

The method I use for zipping:

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

public void zip(String[] files, String zipFile) throws IOException {
        File zipDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/laborator/");
        if (!zipDirectory.exists()) {
            zipDirectory.mkdirs();
        } else {
            System.out.println("folder already exists!");
        }

        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/laborator/" + zipFile)));
        try {
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER_SIZE);
                try {
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].substring(files[i]
                            .lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                    out.putNextEntry(entry);
                    int count;
                    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                        out.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } finally {
                    origin.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
            System.out.println("ziping done");
            sendZip();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what image types do you have: jpg, gifs, pngs, etc?

Comment: @wero The files are jpg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your images are jpgs chances are high that you don't get any decent compression within the ZIP file. So you could try to just put the images uncompressed into the ZIP file which should be considerable faster without increasing the size of the ZIP file:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(files[i].subs...
entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
out.putNextEntry(entry);
```

Comment: Thaaankkkss! One more question, what if I would resize, and upload each file one by one? I have experienced corrupt zips, or cases when an outOfMemory kicked in, so this way nothing reaches the server in case of an error. But Uploading one by one would be more secure, what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: sending a single file might be faster than sending 40 different ones, except if it does not. There are a lot of things to consider - but in the end it the trade-offs depend on your application. Why not go and implement one strategy - and when it really does not work out, look for alternatives.

Comment: The problem is that this is a production app already. What I have faced in the last couple days: 1. corrupt zip, 2. missing images from the archive, 3. entirely missing archive from the server. :( In some of the cases only.

Comment: Why don't you draft another question which addresses these problems? Comments are a bad place to discuss.

Comment: Keep in mind you also have to set the ZipEntry's CRC and size manually if you are using ZipEntry.STORED.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
out.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION);
```

This way no need to change ZipEntry.